# lead and lag on large table 1billion rows

Tags: oracle12c

I have a table T as follows with 1 Billion records. Currently, this table has no Primary key or Indexes.

```
 create table T( 
  day_c date, 
  str_c varchar2(20), 
  comm_c varchar2(20), 
  src_c varchar2(20) 
);
```

some sample data:

```
insert into T  
select to_date('20171011','yyyymmdd') day_c,'st1' str_c,'c1' comm_c,'s1' src_c from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171012','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s1' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171013','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s1' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171014','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s2' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171015','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s2' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171016','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s2' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171017','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s1' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171018','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s1' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171019','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s1' from dual 
union 
select to_date('20171020','yyyymmdd'),'st1','c1','s1' from dual;
```

The expected result is to generate the date ranges for the changes in column src_c.
I have the following code snippet which provides the desired result. However, it is slow as the cost of running lag and lead is quite high on the table.

```
WITH EndsMarked AS ( 
  SELECT 
    day_c,str_c,comm_c,src_c, 
    CASE WHEN src_c= LAG(src_c,1) OVER (ORDER BY day_c) 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IS_START, 
    CASE WHEN src_c= LEAD(src_c,1) OVER (ORDER BY day_c) 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IS_END 
  FROM T 
), GroupsNumbered AS ( 
  SELECT 
    day_c,str_c,comm_c, 
    src_c, 
    IS_START, 
    IS_END, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_START = 1 THEN 1 END) 
      OVER (ORDER BY day_c) AS GroupNum 
  FROM EndsMarked 
  WHERE IS_START=1 OR IS_END=1 
) 
  SELECT 
    str_c,comm_c,src_c, 
    MIN(day_c) AS GROUP_START, 
    MAX(day_c) AS GROUP_END 
    FROM GroupsNumbered 
    GROUP BY str_c,comm_c, src_c,GroupNum 
    ORDER BY groupnum;
```

Output :

```
STR_C   COMM_C  SRC_C   GROUP_START GROUP_END
st1 c1  s1  11-OCT-17   13-OCT-17
st1 c1  s2  14-OCT-17   16-OCT-17
st1 c1  s1  17-OCT-17   20-OCT-17
```

Any suggestion to speed up?

Oracle database :12c.
SGA Memory:20GB
Total CPU:22

Explain plan:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you have license for Database Inmemory from Oracle?

Comment: Unfortunately no! Don't have inmemory database.

Comment: Is there always only 1 record per day_c value?

Comment: ( day_c,str_c,comm_c,src_c) combination is unique in the dataset. dates are contiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order by `day_c` only, or do you need to partition by `str_c` and `comm_c` first? It seems so - in which case I am not sure your query is correct, and Sentinel's solution will need to be adjusted accordingly.

Then:

For some reason (which escapes me), it appears that the `match_recognize` clause (available only since Oracle 12.1) is faster than analytic functions, even when the work done seems to be the same.

In your problem, (1) you must read 1 billion rows from disk, which can't be done faster than the hardware allows (do you REALLY need to do this on all 1 billion rows, or should you archive a large portion of your table, perhaps after performing this identification of GROUP_START and GROUP_END)? (2) you must order the data by `day_c` no matter what method you use, and that is time consuming.

With that said, the tabibitosan method (see Sentinel's answer) will be faster than the start-of-group method (which is close to, but simpler than what you currently have).

The `match_recognize` solution, which will probably be faster than any solution based on analytic functions, looks like this:

```
select str_c, comm_c, src_c, group_start, group_end
from   t
match_recognize(
  partition by str_c, comm_c
  order by     day_c
  measures     x.src_c as src_c,
               first(day_c) as group_start,
               last(day_c)  as group_end
  pattern      ( x y* )
  define y as  src_c = x.src_c
)
--  Add ORDER BY clause here, if needed
;
```

Here is a quick explanation of how this works; for developers who are not familiar with `match_recognize`, I provided links to a few good tutorials in a Comment below this Answer.

The `match_recognize` clause partitions the input rows by `str_c` and `comm_c` and orders them by `day_c`. So far this is exactly the same work that analytic functions do.

Then in the PATTERN and DEFINE clauses I declare and define two "classes" of rows, which will be flagged as X and Y, respectively. X is any row (there are no restrictions on it in the DEFINE clause). However, Y is restricted: it must have the same src_c as the last X row preceding it.

So, in each partition, and reading from the earliest row to the latest (within the partition), I am looking for any number of **matches**, where a match consists of an arbitrary row (marked X), followed by as many Y rows as possible; where Y means "same `src_c as the first row in this match`. So, this will identify sequences of rows where the `src_c` did not change.

For each match that is found, the clause will output the `src_c` value from the X row (which is the same, really, for all the rows in that match), and the first and the last value in the `day_c` column **for that match**. That is what we need to put in the `SELECT` clause of the overall query.

Comment: match_recognize is quite fast compared to lag and lead and I was able to get desired output under 10 minutes. Can you add more description how exactly match_recognize works as it is quite unknown to me? Thanks!

Comment: @Nick - As you may (or may not) know, Stack Overflow is not a teaching website. There are several good tutorials on MATCH_RECOGNIZE, for example https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956 and https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/sql-pattern-matching-deep-dive-part-1 and https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1. There is a lot to read here, but then you will find a very wide variety of problems that can be solved very quickly (and with very efficient solutions) with MATCH_RECOGNIZE. I will just add a few words to my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate one CTE by using the [Tabibito-san](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tabibito-san) (Traveler) method:

```
with Groups as (
  select t.*
       , row_number() over (order by day_c)
       - row_number() over (partition by str_c
                                       , comm_c
                                       , src_c
                            order by day_c) GroupNum
    from t
)
select str_c
     , comm_c
     , src_c
     , min(day_c) GROUP_START
     , max(day_c) GROUP_END
  from Groups
 group by str_c
     , comm_c
     , src_c
     , GroupNum
```